# "Наитие" и "идти" — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Интересно, слово "наитие" происходит от "найти" или "снизойти", или мне это только кажется?

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы. Наитие - от "идти",( праслав.-i-ti)- то, что нашло на человека, ниспослано.В русском яз. корень-и- звучит как -й-после приставок: найти, зайти, прийти подойти.Так что все они от  идти.